# Prove that any prime factor of $ ( x!+1)$ is larger than$ x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

I want to prove the statement "Any prime factor of $x!+1$ is larger than $x$."

Any slight hint will be ok.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assume $p \leq x$ divides $x! + 1$. Then, $p$ also divides $x!$ (as any $y \leq x$ divides $x!$). Thus, $p$ divides both $x!$ and $x! + 1$. Do you see what this forces $p$ to be?

Comment: now I see what I missed. thanks!